# What is groovys equivalent to kotlins set?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, groovy

I want to integrate a snippet into my groovy build.gradle file. Unfortunately the snippet is in kotlin and there is no groovy version presented.

```
openApi {
    apiDocsUrl.set("https://localhost:9000/api/docs")
    outputDir.set(file("$buildDir/docs"))
    outputFileName.set("swagger.json")
    waitTimeInSeconds.set(10)
    forkProperties.set("-Dspring.profiles.active=special")
}
```

I've tried to replace `.set` with `=` but that doesn't seem to work.
There are several articles on how to move from groovy to kotlin but I wasn't able to find out the groovy version of `.set` from them.

Comment: show, what you tried

Comment: normally `=` could replace set. but we have to see what is openApi. if this does not work - then provide the exception.

Comment: `.set()` works in Groovy as well (it is actually just a method on the field, which is of type [Property](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/Property.html#set-T-) - it has nothing to do with the language you are using). What error are you getting?

Comment: For reference, the gradle plugin extension class we are actually operating against here is https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/org/springdoc/openapi/gradle/plugin/OpenApiExtension.kt